# pthread_attr_setstacksize and pthread_exit

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading

I have a question about C concurrency programming in Embedded System with about 64Mb Ram.
Especially, I want to reduce the default memory used by a Thread, so I have defined:

```
pthread_attr_t attr_test;
size_t stacksize = 0x186A0; // 100Kbyte
pthread_attr_init(&attr_test);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr_test, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);    
pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr_test, stacksize);
```

So, When the Thread starts, it uses only 100Kbyte of virtual Memory.
BUT when the Thread ends and calls pthread_exit, the virtual Memory used by the process, increases rapidly!....

Why? What can I do?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:

***Thread ->***

```
void *thread_test(void *arg1) {
    int *param;
    param = (int*)arg1;

    printf("Thread %d start\n", *param);
    pthread_cond_wait(&condition[*param], &mutex[*param]);
    printf("Thread %d stop\n",*param);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

***Main ->***

```
int main(void) {
    pthread_t IDthread[MAX_THREADS];
    int param[MAX_THREADS];
    int pointer;
    int i, keyb;
    void *stkaddr;
    size_t stacksize;

    puts("!!! THREAD TEST !!!");
    printf("Process ID %d\n\n", getpid());

    for(i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_cond_init(&condition[i], NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex[i], NULL);
        IDthread[i] = 0;
        param[i] = i;

    }

    stacksize = 0x186A0; // 100Kbyte

    pthread_attr_init(&attr_test);

    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr_test, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    /* setting the size of the stack also */
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr_test, stacksize);

    pointer = 0;


    do {
        keyb = getchar();
        if (keyb == '1')
        {
            if (pointer < MAX_THREADS)
            {
                pthread_create(&IDthread[pointer], &attr_test, thread_test, &param[pointer]);
                sleep(1);
                pointer++;
            }
            else
                puts("MAX Threads Number");
        }

        if (keyb == '2')
        {
            if (pointer != 0)
            {
                pointer--;
                pthread_cond_signal(&condition[pointer]);
                sleep(1);
            }
            else
                puts("0 Thread is running");
        }

    } while (keyb != '0');
    printf("FINE\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Use debugger and interrupt when the memory usage grows to see what actually happens.

Comment: @timrau 

The problem is that the Thread has only this code:
'
printf("Thread %d stop\n",*param);
pthread_exit(0);
'

So, there is nothing to debug...

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the code? How do you know that memory is increasing after pthread_exit is called? Can't it be related to the main thread?

Comment: @fhsilva I have now posted the code. It simply creates a new thread when you press "1" and it sends a signal when you press "2"...
I saw that memory usage get Up using "TOP" on linux shell

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with the joinable or detached threads, quoting from the manual:

> Only when a
>          terminated joinable thread has been joined are the last of its
>          resources released back to the system.  When a detached thread
>          terminates, its resources are automatically released back to the
>          system

you can make the thread detachable with:

```
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(3)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I use this: ' pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr_test, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);'

Is not right?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your test.
At first, pthread_attr_setstacksize has the following documentation:

*The stack size attribute determines the **minimum size** (in bytes) that will be allocated for threads created using the thread attributes object attr.*

So each thread could use more than what you have set. But more than that, threads may allocate memory from the OS to use as stack. And this also applies to the main thread.

Therefore I don't think there is a way to achieve what you want by looking at the result of top command, since this information is only visible from within the thread itself.

Also note that the virtual memory used by the process is not related to the amount of RAM used by the process.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58614/measuring-stack-usage-for-linux-multi-threaded-app) is something you can try to check the total stack of a thread.