# How to get a callstack trace of debug process by WinDbg library

Tags: c++, windbg

I need to get the callstack trace of debug process by windbg library.
So, answers that could help with theory also are welcome.
Thank for help!

Note 0:
I think the question could be more understandable in this form:
How to parse the stack to frames to get the function calls and args?

Note:
For example, i can in some place of process, by breakpoint, get the ESP register value, but how to parse it? Or is there other way?

Note 2:
The similar question was there: [How do I determine detailed call-stack information in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585636/how-do-i-determine-detailed-call-stack-information-in-c)

Comment: If I understand correctly you would like to use the windbg engine in C++ to obtain a callstack? If by "windbg library" you mean [`dbgeng`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-engine-overview) then you need to [`set a breakpoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-breakpoints) and then [`examine the stack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/examining-the-stack-trace) trace.

Comment: 64 bit or 32 bit? These differ very much. Start using `~`, `k` and `r` to see if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using dbgeng, see the prototype below. You may need to make adjustments to have it compiled as I took it from a bigger project ([NetExt](https://github.com/rodneyviana/netext/blob/master/ClrMemDiagExt/DebugApi.cs)).

```
#include <dbgeng.h>
    IDebugClient *Client;
    PDEBUG_CONTROL5 Control;
    PDEBUG_SYMBOLS5 symbol;
    HRESULT Hr;


    Hr = S_OK;

    if ((Hr = DebugCreate(__uuidof(IDebugClient),
                          (void **)&Client)) != S_OK)
    {
        return Hr;
    }

    if ((Hr = Client->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDebugControl5),
                                  (void **)&Control)) == S_OK)
    {



                DEBUG_STACK_FRAME_EX listFrames[100] = {0};

                UINT total = 0;

                Client->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDebugSymbols5),
                                (void **)&symbol)
                if (Control->GetStackTraceEx(0, 0, 0, &listFrames, 100, &total) == S_OK)
                {

                    for (UINT i=0; i < total; i++)
                    {
                        printf("%i\n", i);
                        printf("\tfInstructionOffset = %p\n", listFrames[i].InstructionOffset);

                        printf("\tfReturnOffset = %p\n", listFrames[i].ReturnOffset);

                        printf("\tFrameOffset = %p\n", listFrames[i].FrameOffset);

                        printf("\tInlineFrameContext = %p\n", listFrames[i].InlineFrameContext);

                        std::string strSymbol('\0', 100);
                        UINT size, displ = 0;

                        if (symbol->GetNameByOffset(listFrames[i].InstructionOffset, const_cast<char*>(strSymbol.c_str()), 100, &size, &displ) == S_OK)
                        {

                            strSymbol.resize(size);

                        }

                        printf("\tFunction = %s\n", strSymbol.c_str());


                    }                   
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you prefer c++ instead of c you can use engextcpp framework provided with windbg sdk

sample code that provides a clickable dml link which when clicked will print the callstack at current Instruction Pointer

contents of directory prior to compiling

```
D:\barebones>ls
barebones.cpp  barebones.def
```

source code

```
D:\barebones>cat barebones.cpp

#include <engextcpp.cpp>
#pragma comment (lib ,"dbgeng.lib")
class EXT_CLASS : public ExtExtension
{
public:
    EXT_COMMAND_METHOD(barebones);
};
EXT_DECLARE_GLOBALS();
EXT_COMMAND(barebones,"","")
{
        DmlCmdExec( "CallStack\n","kb");
}
```

contents of def file

```
D:\barebones>cat barebones.def
EXPORTS

DebugExtensionInitialize
DebugExtensionUninitialize
DebugExtensionNotify
barebones
```

init vs devcmd prompt

```
D:\barebones>runvs

D:\barebones>pushd .

D:\barebones>cd /d "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\"

c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools>vsdevcmd.bat
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.4
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************

c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools>popd
```

contents of directory post compiling and linking

```
D:\barebones>cl /Zi /W3 /EHsc /Od /LD /nologo /I e:\windjs\windbg_18362\inc barebones.cpp /link /release /def:barebones.def /nologo
barebones.cpp
   Creating library barebones.lib and object barebones.exp

D:\barebones>ls -lg
total 7684
-rw-rw-rw-  1 0     247 2019-10-03 16:46 barebones.cpp
-rw-rw-rw-  1 0      96 2019-10-03 16:09 barebones.def
-rw-rw-rw-  1 0  373248 2019-10-03 16:54 barebones.dll
-rw-rw-rw-  1 0    1198 2019-10-03 16:54 barebones.exp
-rw-rw-rw-  1 0    2520 2019-10-03 16:54 barebones.lib
-rw-rw-rw-  1 0  460094 2019-10-03 16:54 barebones.obj
-rw-rw-rw-  1 0 6500352 2019-10-03 16:54 barebones.pdb
-rw-rw-rw-  1 0  512000 2019-10-03 16:54 vc140.pdb

D:\barebones>
```

usage

```
.load {path to barebones.dll}
type !barbones and hit enter 
click the link Named CallStack to get a stacktrace
```

[image]