# Memory allocation when a pointer is assigned

Tags: memory, memory-management, fortran

I am trying to avoid memory allocation and local copy in my code. Below is a small example :

```
module test

  implicit none

  public

  integer, parameter :: nb = 1000
  type :: info
    integer n(nb)
    double precision d(nb)
  end type info

  type(info), save :: abc
  type(info), target, save :: def

  contains

    subroutine test_copy(inf)

      implicit none

      type(info), optional :: inf
      type(info) :: local

      if (present(inf)) then
         local = inf
      else
         local = abc
      endif

      local%n = 1
      local%d = 1.d0

    end subroutine test_copy

    subroutine test_assoc(inf)

      implicit none

      type(info), target, optional :: inf
      type(info), pointer :: local

      if (present(inf)) then
         local => inf
      else
         local => def
      endif

      local%n = 1
      local%d = 1.d0

    end subroutine test_assoc

end module test

program run

  use test
  use caliper_mod

  implicit none

  type(ConfigManager), save :: mgr

  abc%n = 0
  abc%d = 0.d0
  def%n = 0
  def%d = 0.d0

  ! Init caliper profiling
  mgr = ConfigManager_new()
  call mgr%add("runtime-report(mem.highwatermark,output=stdout)")
  call mgr%start

  ! Call subroutine with copy
  call cali_begin_region("test_copy")
  call test_copy()
  call cali_end_region("test_copy")

  ! Call subroutine with pointer
  call cali_begin_region("test_assoc")
  call test_assoc()
  call cali_end_region("test_assoc")

  ! End caliper profiling
  call mgr%flush()
  call mgr%stop()
  call mgr%delete()

end program run
```

As far as i understand, the subroutine `test_copy` should produce a local copy while the subroutine `test_assoc` should only assign a pointer to some existing object. However, memory profiling with caliper leads to :

```
$ ./a.out 
Path       Min time/rank Max time/rank Avg time/rank Time %   Allocated MB 
test_assoc      0.000026      0.000026      0.000026 0.493827     0.000021 
test_copy       0.000120      0.000120      0.000120 2.279202     0.000019
```

What looks odd is that Caliper shows the exact same amount of memory allocated whatever the value of the parameter `nb`. Am I using the right tool the right way to track memory allocation and local copy ?

Test performed with gfortran 11.2.0 and [Caliper](https://github.com/LLNL/Caliper) 2.8.0.

Comment: In `test_copy()`, `local` is (indeed) purely local and its content is never used. It's not impossible that the compiler simply throw it out without even allocating it. Try adding a `write(*,*)` of any element of `local` at the end of the routine, to force the compiler allocating it.

Comment: @PierU the subroutines `test_copy` and `test_assoc` both change the value of local%n and local%d. Adding `write(*,*) local%n(nb), local%d(nb)` has no impact on the allocated memory printed in the caliper report.

Comment: The subroutine change the `local` variable,  but the content is not used at any point. So a clever compiler might see it and skip this part of the code. But OK, this is not what happens here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `local` object is just a simple small scalar, albeit containing an array component, and will be very likely placed on the stack.

A stack is a pre-allocated part of memory of fixed size. Stack "allocation" is actually just a change of value of the stack pointer which is just one integer value. No actual memory allocation from the operating system takes place during stack allocation. There will be no change in the memory the process occupies.

Comment: The `local` object does not contain the arrays `local%n` and `local%d` ? My understanding was the following : the statement `local=abc` creates a copy of `abc%n` and `abc%d` inside `local%n` and `local%d`. EDIT : I am trying to measure this copy.

Comment: It does. But they are small. They fit in the stack and the stack is pre-allocated. Try making them big (tens or hundreds of MB). Then, depending on your compiler and compiler settings you will either get heap allocation or a stack overflow error. Do not remember to actually write something in the array.

Comment: Another option is static memory. That can only be used for non-recursive procedures.

Comment: What is the recommended tool to monitor the stack usage of a subroutine ?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58614/measuring-stack-usage-for-linux-multi-threaded-app When debugging, you can often just print the address of some dummy variable placed last on the stack.

Comment: "A stack is a pre-allocated part of memory of fixed size"... Is it? To me, stack allocations happen at runtime when needed (upon entering a routine for the local variables of the routine for instance). So not a "pre-allocation".

Comment: @PierU Stack is normally fixed. Stack "allocation" is just changing the value of the stack pointer. There can also be unlimited stack, but that just comolicates the matter and it is an exception.

Comment: OK, you meant that the stack space itself is pre-allocated, not the variables themselves...

Comment: @user1824346 And you can also print and track the value of the stack pointer.